# How to reduce code for reactive form validation in angular7

Tags: angular6, angular7, angular-reactive-forms, angular8

I am trying to reduce code in reactive form validation.I have lot of code for reactive form validation so my page is loading too slow.So how to resovle that issue to increase speed.
I do not know.If anyone know please help to find the solution.

```
 this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        firstName: [null],
        lastName: [null] 
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reset all your form controls by using reset method of RxFormGroup. You just need to install `@rxweb/reactive-form-validators`.

```
resetForm() {
    this.registerForm.resetForm({ resetType: ResetFormType.ControlsOnly });
  }
```

Here is the complete component code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { RxFormGroup, RxFormBuilder, FormGroupExtension, ResetFormType} from "@rxweb/reactive-form-validators";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { FormArray } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: "app-reset-controlsOnly-validator",
  templateUrl: "./reset-controls-only.component.html"
})
export class ResetControlsOnlyValidatorComponent implements OnInit {
  registerForm: RxFormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: RxFormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.registerForm = <RxFormGroup>this.formBuilder.group({
      firstName: [""]
    });
  }

  resetForm() {
    this.registerForm.resetForm({ resetType: ResetFormType.ControlsOnly });
  }
}
```

Please refer this working [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-njdyfw?file=src%2Fapp%2Freset-controls-only.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

You can reset all Form values in once by

```
resetfn()
{
   this.registerForm.reset();
}
```